# What is the minimum number of bytes per node on a 64-bit machine?

Tags: linked-list, byte, bit

> On a 64-bit machine, what is the minimum number of bytes per node
> needed to implement a Singly Linked List, assuming that each node
> stores a reference to its value?

Could someone explain why the answer is `16 bytes`?

Answer (score 1):

On a 64-bit computer, sizeof(node) is 16 (4 bytes for contents/Value, 4 bytes of padding to properly align the next pointer on an 8-byte boundary, and 8 bytes for next).